# Subquery in select

Tags: sql, select, subquery

How do i make this sub work?

```
Select a.group IN (select b.ref from b) from a
```

Comment: What do you want this query to do?

Comment: Select a.group from a where a.group IN (select b.ref from b)

Comment: With SQL questions you should always also tag the DBMS used (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appears to want :

```
select a.*
from a 
where exists (select 1 from b where b.ref = a.group);
```